# Return dynamic string concatenated with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have the following in my javascript code using jquery:

```
$('.attrs span:nth-child(1)').text() + ' | ' + $('.attrs span:nth- 
child(2)').text() + ' | ' + $('.attrs span:nth-child(3)').text() ...
```

Though the number of children span elements will change so I have worked on it dynamically like so:

```
      function getString(containerElem) {
            var str = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < containerElem.children().length; i++) {
                    ((i + 1) == containerElem.children().length) ? str += '$(\'.attrs span:nth-child('  + (i + 1) +  ')\').text()' : str += '$(\'.attrs span:nth-child('  + (i + 1) +  ')\').text() + \'  \' + ';
            }
            return str;
       }
```

When I return it as a string the jQuery will not work as the `$` is a string now as well, can I do this using some flag or global variable to add to the string somehow ie `$.getString() + $.getString2()...` depending on how many span elements my container has?

Comment: If something like this `$('.attrs span:nth-child(1)').text()` is returned as a string, You could use eval(Yourstring), but if I was you, i would look for a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to know how many `<span>` you have, you can just select them all with
`$('.attrs span')`.

Then, just get their text values with `innerText` and use `Array#join` to create your `String`:

```js
let spans = $('.attrs span');

let result = spans.get().map(e => e.innerText).join(' | ');
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attrs">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery `children` method can be called with a selector as argument, to limit the list of children to that selector. This way you can find all child elements that are a `SPAN`, iterate over that list of elements read the inner text.

```js
function getString(containerElem) {
  var str = '';

  containerElem.children('span').each(function(i, element) {
    str += jQuery(element).text();
  });

  return str;
}

console.log(getString(jQuery('.attrs')));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="attrs">
  <span>1</span>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>3</span>
  <span>4</span>
  <span>5</span>
</div>
```